# $\mathbf K1.1$ is sound and strongly complete w.r.t. frames for which $R$ is a partial function

Tags: logic, modal-logic

> (Blackburn et al.'s Modal Logic, Ex 4.3.1): Let $1.1$ be the axiom $\diamond p\to\square p$. Show that $\mathbf K1.1$ is sound and strongly complete with respect to the class of all frames $(W,R)$ such that $R$ is a partial function.

Firstly, I am confused about the meaning of a partial function. After a quick Google search, I found out that a partial function $f$ from $X$ to $Y$ is essentially a function $f: S\to Y$ where $S\subset X$ (possibly improper). In other words, we are basically allowing the function to forget about some values in the domain. That being said, we know $R\subset W\times W$. If $R$ is a partial function, then the idea is that we can have isolated worlds, right? In addition, one world can be mapped to only one other (because $f: S\to Y$ is a function, so it is well-defined).

Just want to quickly verify my solution.

1. Suppose the class of all frames $(W,R)$ in which $R$ is a partial function is denoted by $P$. Then, for every frame $\mathfrak F \in P$, we show $\mathfrak F\Vdash \diamond p\to\square p$. $\mathfrak F\Vdash \diamond p\to\square p$ if and only if $\mathfrak F,w\Vdash \diamond p\to\square p$ for all $w\in W$. Consider arbitrary $w\in W$. Suppose $\mathfrak F,w\Vdash \diamond p$. Then, there exists $v\in W$ such that $wRv$ and $\mathfrak F,v\Vdash p$. Moreover, for all $v' \in W, v'\ne v$, we have $w\lnot Rv'$. This is because $R$ is a partial function. Hence, $\mathfrak F,w\Vdash \square p$. One direction is done!
2. Next, I want to show that if $\mathfrak F\Vdash \diamond p\to\square p$ (for all frames in $P$), i.e. $\mathfrak F,w\Vdash \diamond p\to\square p$ for all $w\in W$, then $R$ is a partial function. This is easily done too, and I am skipping the proof.

Another question I have is, where are soundness and completeness coming into play, exactly? When we say soundness, we want $\vdash \implies \Vdash$. For completeness, it's the other way round. Since $1.1$ is put into the axioms of $\mathbf K1.1$, perhaps the first part (1) of my solution corresponds with proving soundness, i.e. seeing if the axiom is valid in all frames of a particular type? If yes, then the other part (2) is probably completeness, but I do not really see how.

Could someone help me really understand if what I'm doing is right, and why I am doing it? I have difficulty understanding the bigger picture of completeness and soundness in modal logic. Thanks!

Comment: Obviously Ax.1.1 is the axiom of K1.1., but this is not enough for *soundness*. Soundness means that if $\vdash_K \varphi$, then $(W,R) \Vdash \varphi$. Thus, for soundness you have to verify that Ax.1.1 holds in the corersponding $(W,R)$.

Comment: Strong completeness means that if $\Gamma \vDash \varphi$, then $\Gamma \vdash_K \varphi$, where  $\Gamma \vDash \varphi$ means: if $(W,R) \Vdash \alpha$, for every $\alpha \in \Gamma$, then $(W,R) \Vdash \varphi$

Comment: I see that makes sense! $\vdash_K\varphi$ would then mean that $R$ is a partial function ($\color{red}{???}$) and, using this fact, I show that $(W, R)\Vdash\varphi$? I believe this is what soundness is. Correct me if I'm wrong. I'm pretty unsure about the question in red.

Comment: In strong completeness, what $\Gamma$ do I pick?

Comment: A set of premises.

Comment: Correct; you have to show that Ax.1.1 holds in a class where $R$ is partial (soundness) and (presumably) you have to exploit the "partiality" property of $R$ in the construction of the canonical model used to prove that if the formula holds, than we have a proof of it (from premises and modal axiom) (completeness)

Comment: See e.g. [Basic ML](https://mally.stanford.edu/notes.pdf), page 67 for Soundness, page 70 for Completeness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof sketch aims to show that the 1.1-formula defines the class of frames whose accessibility relations are partial functions. But that is a frame correspondence result and not a frame completeness result, which you are asked to show in the exercise.

But there is a connection here between frame correspondence and frame completeness. To show the completeness result you may use what Blackburn et al. call a completeness-via-canonicity argument: Prove that the 1.1-formula is canonical for partial functionhood. That is prove (i) that the canonical frame of every normal modal logic containing the 1.1-formula is partially functional and (ii) that the 1.1-formula is valid in every partially functional frame.

Now your frame correspondence result has already covered (ii). What is still left is (i). To show (i), let $ \diamond p \rightarrow \square p \in \Lambda$, where $\Lambda$ is any normal logic, and Let $\mathcal{F}^{\Lambda} = (W^{\Lambda}, R^{\Lambda})$ be the canonical frame for $\Lambda$. Suppose that $R^{\Lambda}st, R^{\Lambda}sv$, for arbitrary $s,t,v \in W^{\Lambda}$ and that $\psi \in t$. So, $\diamond \psi \in s$. As $\diamond \psi \rightarrow \square \psi \in s$, we then have that $\square \psi \in s$. As $R^{\Lambda}sv$ it follows that $\psi \in v$. Hence $t \subseteq v$. Analogously, it can be shown that $v \subseteq t$.

Comment: Just to confirm - Part (1) of my argument is the step (ii) of frame completeness you mention, and you've done step (i) in your answer. Then Part (2) of my argument corresponds to soundness, right?

Comment: Not quite. Your part (1) corresponds to (ii), yes. But (ii) corresponds to frame soundness, not to frame completeness. The latter is covered by (i). So the name 'completeness-via canonicity' is a bit misleading as (i) and (ii) together yield correctness and completeness of the logic.

Comment: but frame soundness is $\vdash \to\Vdash$, right? In (ii) I start by assuming $\mathfrak F\Vdash (1.1)$, so it really feels like a completeness argument. Not sure what I'm missing. Could you clarify?

Comment: (ii) is the claim that the 1.1. formula is valid in every partially functional frame. So you cannot start a proof of (ii) by assuming this claim. Besides completeness proofs using canonical models never start in this way.